# Live view update after form submission with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There a page on my app where i display comments made by users. When a taps on Edit Comment, a modal is open where the user can make edits to his/her comments and submission to the database is successful. Now my issue is the user wouldn't have to refresh the page before they see the update they just did. i want the edited text to be updated in the view

VIEW

```
  {
    postComments.map((item) => (
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        hideChevron={true}
        avatar={{uri:item.avatar}}
        key={item.id}
        title={item.author.member.firstname + ' ' + item.author.member.lastname}
        subtitle={
          <View >
            <Text style={{paddingLeft:10, fontSize:16, color:'#4a4a4a', fontFamily:'HelveticaNeue-Light'}}>{item.text}</Text>

            <View style={{position:'absolute',right:0, bottom:0}}>
            <Text> 
            <Text 
            onPress={()=>callEditModal(item)}
            style={{color:'#36a', fontSize:18}}>Edit | </Text> 
            </Text>
            </View>

          </View>
        }
      />
    ))
  }


    <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={visible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <Header
          centerComponent={{ text: 'Edit Comment', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
          rightComponent={{ icon: 'close', color: '#fff', onPress: () => closeEditModal(), }}
          backgroundColor= '#00aae0'
          containerStyle={{
          top: -20,
        }}
        />
            <View >

            <TextInput
              value={userComment} 
              onChangeText={setEditComment} 
              style={{padding:10,backgroundColor:'#fafafa', height:150}} 
              mode="flat" multiline={true} 
              numberOfLines={2} label='' 
               />


          <Button style={{alignSelf:'flex-end',height:50, margin:10, justifyContent:"center", width:"40%"}}
                icon="send"
                type='material' 
                mode="contained"
                color="#00aae0"
                uppercase={false}
                onPress={() => {saveComment()}} >
              Save Edit
            </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
```

FUNCTION

```
saveComment = () => {
  alert(this.state.userComment);
}
```

How do i make i live update?

Comment: update your list once user has done with editing. In your case list is `postComments `, just update the list with the new comment and refresh the component by `setState()`

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: could you get what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

if `user wouldn't have to refresh the page` means not using `setState()` i doubt its possible. you didn't say which type of approach you use to store data in app. but if you use any database, after editing update the database and reinitialize your views from there(calling a function to catch data from app DB and put data in state for e.g).

i use `realm` in react native, so code would be like this:

```
updateState() {
        const devs = realm.objects('user_devices');
        this.setState({ devices: devs });
    }
```

and whenever i change a thing in my DB and i want user to see that i call this method.